# how can i add some triple to my Ontology by Jena?

Tags: java, semantic-web, jena, ontology, owl

I have `instance1` of `class1` and `instance2` of `class2`. Also I have defined `HasName(object property)` in my ontology. Now, how can I add the triple (`instance1   HasName     instance2`)  to my ontology by jena?

Comment: For the record, apparently "Jena" is the Jena Semantic framework, see http://jena.sourceforge.net/ontology/

Answer (score 12):

Here's a way without dealing with intermediate `Statements`.

```
// RDF Nodes -- you can make these immutable in your own vocabulary if you want -- see Jena's RDFS, RDF, OWL, etc vocabularies
Resource class1 = ResourceFactory.createResource(yourNamespace + "class1");
Resource class2 = ResourceFactory.createResource(yourNamespace + "class1");
Property hasName = ResourceFactory.createProperty(yourNamespace, "hasName"); // hasName property

// The RDF Model
Model model = ... // Use your preferred method to get an OntModel, InfModel, or just regular Model

Resource instance1 = model.createResource(instance1Uri);
Resource instance2 = model.createResource(instance2Uri);

// Create statements
instance1.addProperty(RDF.type, class1); // Classification of instance1
instance2.addProperty(RDF.type, class2); // Classification of instance2
instance1.addProperty(hasName, instance2); // Edge between instance1 and instance2
```

You could also chain some of these calls in a builder-ish pattern.

```
Resource instance2 = model.createResource(instance2Uri).addProperty(RDF.type, class2);
model.createResource(instance1Uri).addProperty(RDF.type, class1).addProperty(hasName, instance2);
```

Comment: +1: I like the builder-pattern style construction, I hadn't seen that before! :)

Comment: Hi. The answer is amazing, but I do have a doubt. Whats the difference between creating triples using a Statement and using resources as your solution above? Please do clarify this for me. Thanks

Comment: would you please help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545298/creating-and-inferining-knowledge-about-a-rdf-owl-model

Answer (score 2):

In Jena, this can be done by creating an instance of a [Statement](http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Statement.html) (a triple, or quad), then committing the statement to an instance of a [Model](http://jena.sourceforge.net/javadoc/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html).

For example, consider the following:

```
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(); // an ont model instance
...
Statement s = ResourceFactory.createStatement(subject, predicate, object);
model.add(s); // add the statement (triple) to the model
```

Where `subject`, `predicate` and `object` are instance elements of your triple with types conforming to the interface for [ResourceFactory.createStatement()](http://bit.ly/cLxRKk).

Comment: would you please help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545298/creating-and-inferining-knowledge-about-a-rdf-owl-model