# Adding an ObjectProperty assertion

Tags: rdf, jena, owl

I am facing a problem while Adding an Individual of an OWL class (Class A) having many ObjectProperty (Say A1, A2...) with range as some other OWL class (Range of A1 be OWL Class B, Range of A2 be OWL class C ...) and hence classes B, C have some DatatypeProperty or ObjectProperty with some specific datatype like String, float, double.
To my knowledge we can add individuals like:

```
Individual i = A.createIndividual(NS+"nameOfIndividual");
```

and then add properties to it like:

```
i.addProperty(Property prop, "value");
```

but in this way all values are added as String Literal and bear no reference to the range defined for that property.  Further I find it difficult to drill down to the base datatype property if the class level hierarchy is more than two levels.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i add some trrriple to my ontology by jena?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975425/how-can-i-add-some-trrriple-to-my-ontology-by-jena)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Further I find it difficult to drill down to the base datatype property if the class level hierarchy is more than two levels."  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The method signature for `Resource.addProperty` is overloaded. If you look at the [Javadoc](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html), you'll see that it has the following polymorphic variants:

- `addProperty(Property p, RDFNode o)`
- `addProperty(Property p, String o)`
- `addProperty(Property p, String lexicalForm, RDFDatatype datatype)`
- `addProperty(Property p, String o, String l)`

The second variant, taking a string, is just a convenience for adding a literal value. The first variant is what you want. `RDFNode` is the supertype of `Resource`, and hence of `Individual`, `OntClass`, etc. So all you need to do is pass in a value which is already an RDFNode.

To make this concrete, here is how you assert a relationship between two individuals:

```
Individual ai = A.createIndividual(NS+"nameOfIndividualInA");
Individual bi = B.createIndividual(NS+"nameOfIndividualInB");

Property p = A.createObjectProperty( NS + "p" );

// either
ai.addProperty( p, bi );

// or
model.add( ai, p, bi );
```

**Update**

In response to the comments, here is some actual runnable code that shows various ways of invoking these API methods:

```
package examples;

import java.util.Calendar;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.TypeMapper;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDatatype;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;

public class AddPropertiesExample
{
    public static final String NS = "http://example.com/test#";

    private Property p;
    private Resource r, s;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new AddPropertiesExample().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        Model m = createModel();

        // add property values using the Model.add( Resource, Property, RDFNode) signature
        m.add( r, p, s );
        m.add( r, p, ResourceFactory.createPlainLiteral( "foo" ) );
        m.add( r, p, ResourceFactory.createLangLiteral( "le foo", "fr" ) );
        m.add( r, p, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral( 42 ) );
        m.add( r, p, ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral( Calendar.getInstance() ));

        // ditto using the Model.add( Resource, Property, String ) signature
        m.add( r, p, "This is a plain literal" );

        // ditto using the Model.add( Resource, Property, String, String ) signature
        m.add( r, p, "Das foo", "de" );

        // ditto using the Model.add( Resource, Property, String, RDFDatatype ) signature
        m.add( r, p, "42.42", XSDDatatype.XSDfloat );
        m.add( r, p, "2000-01-01",
               TypeMapper.getInstance().getTypeByName( "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date" ) );

        m.write( System.out, "Turtle" );
    }

    private Model createModel() {
        Model m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();

        p = m.createProperty( NS + "p" );
        r = m.createResource( NS + "r" );
        s = m.createResource( NS + "s" );

        return m;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<http://example.com/test#r>
    <http://example.com/test#p>  "2000-01-01"^^xsd:date , 
         "42.42"^^xsd:float , 
         "Das foo"@de , 
         "This is a plain literal" , 
         "2013-10-28T11:46:35.596Z"^^xsd:dateTime , 
         "42"^^xsd:int , 
         "le foo"@fr , 
         "foo" ;
    <http://example.com/test#p>  <http://example.com/test#s> .
```

Comment: Ian, In order to use the fourth variant `Resource.addProperty(Property p, String o, String l)` , what is the String l argument? Is it a URI of an XSD eg: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int ??

Comment: I am able to add instances using the second variant. But in order to add datatyprProperty with literal values, the porblem persists. My main objective is to add literal values, as per the datatype obtained at runtime using the range of the datatypeProperty in use. I think third and fourth vairant are the ones i need in this case but things are not clear from the javadoc in case for the arguments lexicalForm, and RDFDatatype for 3rd variant and String l in fourth variant. How do we obtain the `RDFDatatype` from `DatatypeProperty.getRange()` ?? I guess then I'll have my solution..

Comment: If I use the following code to add an individual:

`m.add( r, p, "42.42",
               TypeMapper.getInstance().getTypeByName( "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float" ) );`

And then fire a sparql query as follows:

`SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?o 42.42 };`

Will the query return the above added individual entry?